# calculating constant deceleration with time

Tags: physics

The distance between point A and B is 500m, an object is moving at 50m/s, the object will stop exactly at 500m when it's deceleration reaches zero after 5 seconds, the deceleration is constant, how do I calculate the deceleration?

Comment: Can you relate position, velocity and acceleration?

Comment: If an object starts at $50$ m/s, and decelerates to zero in $5$ seconds, it will not travel $500$ meters in that time. I suspect you have described the problem differently than it was meant to be understood.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there seems to be an error and the author does not comment/correct it

Answer (score 1):

If the deceleration is constant, then you cam calculate it easily:
$$d=-\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$
Where $\Delta v$ is the change of speed: 
$$\Delta v=v_{final}-v_{initial}$$
and $\Delta t$ is the change of time (the duration of deceleration):
$$\Delta t=t_{final}-t_{initial}$$